# when use multiple datasource, how to use same name with Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

The two database have some same name tables, for example the table with name summary, when I create repository, an error occurred! what should i do? the error is:

```
@Autowired
SummaryDao summaryDao;
```

> RROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter -
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field summaryDao in
>   com.tc.spider.schedule.logic.combination.CombinationDailyNetLogic
>   required a bean of type 'com.tc.spider.dao.user.SummaryDao' that could
>   not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.tc.spider.dao.user.SummaryDao'
>   in your configuration.

the datasource config file is below:

`

```
package com.tc.spider.config.db;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.sql.DataSource;


@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {
    @Bean(name = "primaryDataSource")
    @Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
    @Primary // 该数据源为主数据源
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.tct")
    public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "secondaryDataSource")
    @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.market")
    public DataSource secondaryDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary // jdbc默认的主数据源
    public JdbcTemplate primaryJdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean(name = "marketJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate marketJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("secondaryDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

`

primary datasource
`

```
package com.tc.spider.config.db;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactoryPrimary", // 配置连接工厂 entityManagerFactory
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerPrimary", // 配置 事物管理器  transactionManager
        basePackages = {"com.tc.spider.dao.user"}) // 设置Repository所在位置
public class PrimaryConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("primaryDataSource")
    private DataSource primaryDataSource;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerPrimary")
    @Primary
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return entityManagerFactoryPrimary(builder).getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactoryPrimary")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryPrimary(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                // 设置数据源
                .dataSource(primaryDataSource)
                // 设置数据源属性
                .properties(getVendorProperties(primaryDataSource))
                // 设置实体类所在位置.扫描所有带有 @Entity 注解的类
                .packages("com.tc.spider.model.user")
                // Spring会将EntityManagerFactory注入到Repository之中.有了 EntityManagerFactory之后,
                // Repository就能用它来创建 EntityManager 了,然后 EntityManager 就可以针对数据库执行操作
                .persistenceUnit("primaryPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    private Map getVendorProperties(DataSource dataSource) {
        return jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource);
    }

    /**
     * 配置事物管理器
     *
     * @param builder
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerPrimary")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerPrimary(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactoryPrimary(builder).getObject());
    }
}
```

`

SecondaryConfig.java this is the second datasource config
`

```
package com.tc.spider.config.db;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Map;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactorySecondary", // 配置连接工厂 entityManagerFactory
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerSecondary", // 配置 事物管理器  transactionManager
        basePackages = {"com.tc.spider.dao.market"}) // 设置Repository所在位置
public class SecondaryConfig {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondaryDataSource")
    private DataSource secondaryDataSource;

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerSecondary")
    public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return entityManagerFactorySecondary(builder).getObject().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactorySecondary")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactorySecondary(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                // 设置数据源
                .dataSource(secondaryDataSource)
                // 设置数据源属性
                .properties(getVendorProperties(secondaryDataSource))
                // 设置实体类所在位置.扫描所有带有 @Entity 注解的类
                .packages("com.tc.spider.model.market") //设置实体类所在位置
                // Spring会将EntityManagerFactory注入到Repository之中.有了 EntityManagerFactory之后,
                // Repository就能用它来创建 EntityManager 了,然后 EntityManager 就可以针对数据库执行操作
                .persistenceUnit("secondaryPersistenceUnit")
                .build();
    }

    @Autowired
    private JpaProperties jpaProperties;

    private Map getVendorProperties(DataSource dataSource) {
        return jpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(dataSource);
    }

    /**
     * 配置事物管理器
     *
     * @param builder
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "transactionManagerSecondary")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerSecondary(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactorySecondary(builder).getObject());
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Can you add your dataSource config?

Comment: how to add pictures?

Comment: Have you defined `SummaryDao` at all?

Comment: There are two SummaryDao file that correspond to different data sources

Comment: Did you try to add @Primary for primaryDataSource?